# unexpected behaviour using code from pinescript docs, time function does not color the correct time background

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The colored background is in another time range.
Not really sure of the error, is there another way to do this task ?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Session bars", "", true)
inSession = not na(time(timeframe.period, "1100-1300"))
bgcolor(inSession ? color.silver : na)
```

the result is included in a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript the **time** function refers to the time of the provider of your data : in your case BITSTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The `time()` function has a third argument called `timezone`.

> ***timezone (series string)*** Timezone of the `session` argument. Can only be used when a `session` is specified. Optional. The default is
> syminfo.timezone. Can be specified in GMT notation (e.g. "GMT-5") or
> as an IANA time zone database name (e.g. "America/New_York").

You can pass your timezone as a string then it will work as intended.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Session bars", "", true)
timezone = input.string("GMT-7", "Timezone")
inSession = not na(time(timeframe.period, "1100-1300", timezone))
bgcolor(inSession ? color.silver : na)
```

[image]